# I'm not able to start working on Fiddler on my Window 7 system?

Tags: fiddler

Please help me start using Fiddler on my Windows 7 system. As I've already done all the settings/changes required for it as per Fiddler's doc.

I wanna connect my Android and iOS device through it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to do the following:

- make sure your computer and mobile devices are connected to the same network (wifi for example)
- on your iOS device, you must enter the proxy address (IP and fiddler proxy port) in the wifi connection settings; should be at the bottom of the wifi connection settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler can be used to capture traffic from iOS and Android devices.

Briefly:

- Connect both devices to the same network, and make the iOS/Android device discoverable
- Allow remote devices to connect to Fiddler
- Edit the proxy on the Android device to point to Fiddler.

More specific steps are described in the [How to: Capture Android Traffic with Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler) and [How To: Capture iOS Traffic with Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-ios-traffic-with-fiddler) Telerik blog posts.